# Does this kind of polynomials have atleast two real roots?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

This is an exercise problem in the real analysis book I am currently reading, in the chapter after intermediate value theorem.

##### "Let $p(x):=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n.$ If $a_0a_n<0,$ show that p has atleast two real roots...

I can easily see this is true if the degree of p is even.

###### Case I:- if $a_0 < 0$ then $a_n>0$, and hence as x becomes larger it tends to infinity on both sides and hence by IVT, we can conclude that it has atleast 2 real roots...

###### Case II:- if $a_0>0$, then $a_n<0$, and hence as x becomes larger it tends to minus infinity on both sides and hence by IVT, we can conclude that it has atleast 2 real roots...

But for odd degree polynomials... Lets consider

##### $x^3+3x-2023$, clearly it has only  one real root...

But on the book it is not mentioned it is true for even degree polynomials only...
Does the author forgot to mention it? Or Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Even worse, what if $n=1$? This looks like a serious error. Books do contain them.

Comment: It is true if $n$ is even though.

Comment: It is an error, but I strongly suspect it was just that the book accidently dropped the assumption that $n$ was even, not some serious oversight.